# Creating laravel multiple mysql connection from current database

Tags: laravel

I want to store multiple database connection in my current laravel db.
i need to connect these via dropdown and generate reports on the fly.
what is the best way to configure this

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a table "connection(strings)" in your 1st db and create a model for that table.

After that you can do something like this:

```
$selected = Connection::query()->where('name', 'fromdropdown')->first();
   $connection = $selected;
                config(['database.connections.data' => array(
                    'driver'    => 'sqlsrv',
                    'host' => $connection['Database_Server'],
                    'database' => $connection['Database_Name'],
                    'username' => $connection['Database_User'],
                    'password' => $connection['Database_Pass']

                )]);

                DB::setDefaultConnection('data');
```

Comment: Sorry but can you be some more precise how will i perform queries from that connection

Comment: Well laravel will always use the default db connection, which we set in the last line :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set multiple database connections in the `app/config/database.php` file.

Example:

```
'default' => 'mysql',

    'connections' => array(

        # Our primary database connection
        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'host1',
            'database'  => 'database1',
            'username'  => 'user1',
            'password'  => 'pass1'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),

        # Our secondary database connection
        'mysql2' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'host2',
            'database'  => 'database2',
            'username'  => 'user2',
            'password'  => 'pass2'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
    )
```

And then just use the connection name in your query:

```
$users = DB::connection('mysql2')->select(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but i will have to add 15 db connections and more will be added in future so i need to put in the current db.