# How to build a custom connection outside of database.php in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am building a system that uses multiple databases. I currently have a custom config file which I am using that has some controls in it. This file is not put through version control.

I would like these databases to be independant of git. I am looking to build a custom connection without using config/database.php

I could of course remove config/database.php from git but I want to keep it neat and make use of my custom config file.

Here is my clientconfig.php to be found in /config folder

```
<?php
$clientDB = '';
if(isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) {
    $apiDomain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    if ( $apiDomain == 'www.example.com' ) {
        $clientDB = 'clientdb_1';
    }
}
return  [

    'client_db' => $clientDB

];
```

I  would like to add my connections in that file too that are found in database.php

```
'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'example'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'example'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'example'),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

    'clientdb_1' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => ('clientdb_1'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'example'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'example'),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

Is there a clean way this can be done?

**EDIT:** I have consired the .env file but it is too messy considering I may have different amount of databases etc. I will still be adding them to database.php which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: I found this, I believe I may be able to set the values dynamically, ill report back and answer if so https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-modify-database-connection-string-in-laravel-5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating laravel multiple mysql connection from current database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038674/creating-laravel-multiple-mysql-connection-from-current-database)

Comment: Yes you can set database connections dynamically using config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to add my own new connection in that file by using `config()`.

```
if ( $apiDomain == 'www.example.com' ) {

    $appUrl   = $apiDomain;
    $clientDB = 'clientdb_1';

    config(['database.connections.clientdb_1' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => $clientDB,
        'username' => 'example',
        'password' => 'example',
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,

    )]);
}
```

NB: This did not work unless my custom config file was loaded **after** database.php. Because it was in alphabetical order I had to rename my file to z_clientconfig.php

Comment: Great! this can be over-right default connection "mysql" also  thank you